# arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc does not find library

Tags: c, gcc, opengl-es, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a c program in the paparazzi autopilot environment with OpenGL ES support for an ARM Mali GPU. I've compiled the libGLESv2 libraries from the Mali SDK, and everything worked fine. Now I'm trying to get the cross-compiler to find such libraries, but it says:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
```

I tried to add the -v option to check the library path and it says:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

I've placed the libGLESv2.so library in the first of such directories but still it doesn't work. What do you suggest?

Thanks,

Davide

Comment: you have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for shared library. Also, can you post your command line for compiling the code

Comment: @terencehill I'm trying to modify the provided makefile to have it compile. I don't really have much control on what is going on because I must compile it inside paparazzi. In any case, I added this to the makefile `$(TARGET).CFLAGS += -L/home/davide/Scaricati/Mali_OpenGL_ES_SDK_v2.4.4/lib/arm -lGLESv2`

Comment: @terencehill I've also tried  ` $(TARGET).LDLAGS += "-L/home/davide/Scaricati/Mali_OpenGL_ES_SDK_v2.4.4/lib/arm"`, which I believe should be the correct one, but not difference

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182272/cannot-find-lglesv2)

> add "link_directories(/home/davide/Scaricati/Mali_OpenGL_ES_SDK_v2.4.4/lib/arm)" in CMakeLists.txt